# Resizing window causing problems

Tags: html, css, web

I want to position a button somewhere on my webpage, but resizing the window is causing the button to move.

Here's the CSS:

```
    .btn-success{
        position: absolute;
        left: 37%;
        bottom: 20%;
    {
```

and HTML:

```
    <button class="btn btn-success btn-large">Buy now!</button>
```

What can I do to prevent this from happening?  If there's anything else I can post that will help, just let me know.  Thanks.

Comment: Dont use a percentage based position, or use a percentage position inside a `position:relative` element with an absolute (px, pt, etc.) width...

Comment: I see.  I have another issue though.  The button goes far enough to the right on a larger resolution, but not far enough on a smaller resolution.  Everything else is fitting except the button. Any ideas?

Comment: I cant say without at least an example of your layout. You should make jsfiddle that illustrates the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As prodigitalson suggested don't use percent. Based on my experience using a percentage will ruin you web design when changing different screen resolution. Use a fix width or height(use .px or .em) instead. In my website I'm using `margin: 0 auto;` to center it and I use a fixed height and width, so on any screen resolution my web design isn't affected.  Here is a guide that helps me to avoid screen resolution problem. [How to Center a Website With CSS](http://buildinternet.com/2008/11/how-to-center-a-website-with-css/).

Comment: Thank you.  Resolution issues are my biggest problem right now.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this button is nested in some content container in HTML. Assuming this container has max-width or width set, you may add position: relative to this container' css.

You need to know that your button will position in relation to first parent that has position relative or absolute.

Comment: The button is not within a container.